# Changing screens by alert in swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, alert

I have no idea how to change screens programatically. I have an alert view and I want to be able to change screen when the user presses the "Ok" button. How do I do this?

Here is my new code:

```
func showAlertController(){
    let tilte = "My Medication"
    let message = NSLocalizedString("Go through Medication guide?", comment: "")
    let cancelButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString("Dismiss", comment: "")
    let otherButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: "")

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)



    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: .Cancel){ action in
        NSLog("User said no")}

    let otherAction = UIAlertAction(title: otherButtonTitle, style: .Default){action in
        // I know I need to put something in here.
        let appointment = Appointment()
        self.presentViewController(appointment, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(otherAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

However now I get a bug saying:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_l1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Comment: When you have "no idea" how to do something, perhaps you should read the documentation. I would suggest the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" as a good place to start.

Comment: I'm looking that up right now, thanks!

Comment: That error says nothing, you should update it with all the stack traces.

Comment: What is a stack trace? @insane-36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add presentViewController inside UIAlertAction closure for "Ok" button, it means that the button is pressed and so you do your stuffs for the button being pressed inside the block.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
     ...
     ...
     func showAlertController(){
        let tilte = "My Medication"
        let message = NSLocalizedString("Go through Medication guide?", comment: "")
        let cancelButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString("Dismiss", comment: "")
        let otherButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: "")

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)



        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: .Cancel){ action in
            NSLog("User said no")}

        let otherAction = UIAlertAction(title: otherButtonTitle, style: .Default){action in
            // I know I need to put something in here.
            let appointmentViewController = AppointmentViewController()
            self.presentViewController(appointmentViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)    
        }

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(otherAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    ...
    ...
}

class AppointmentViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

Comment: Ah, right! But now all this does is just display the same screen again and again. I want it to change screen, how do I make it do that?

Comment: Well haha sorry I made a small mistake there, let me edit it.

Comment: Ah, its cool brother! But I'm having some trouble actually getting the change to happen you see... I want to change it to the Appointment.swift screen and I get an error now

Comment: In other words, how do I define myViewController()?

Comment: Create your own class subclassing UIViewController. You should really go through the documentation and do further research on this. However, I am adding to you a simple viewcontroller class, see my edits.

Comment: I understand what you mean and am reading through that right now. I tried your code above and am still getting an error, I will post an image of what the error is like on the question.

Comment: I edited my question with the new error I am getting @insane-36